# How to pass data from one Jframe to anotherJframe in the form of variable

Tags: java, variables, netbeans-8

I want to get values in all these components and pass these values in another ***`JFrame`*** in form of variables so further, I can save it from that Frame(Another JFrame) to ***`MYSQL`***
[image]

Here the user will enter all value and after clicking next I want all these values will go to next ***`JFrame`*** in the Form of ***Variable***

Please tell me how to do this?
[Youtube References](https://youtu.be/QNTLJc4MaD0)

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the other Jframe when clicking a button on the current frame, just pass the variables in a map to the constructor of the other frame. A map would be useful when there are a lot of variables to be passed, or else you could pass each of the variables as parameters. Write the code to get the values of the individual variables using a key.

Suppose, these are the variables you've got from the jframe components :

```
String name = "Arun";
String address = "ken";
String city = "clt";
String gender = "Male";
```

Then you could pass the values in a HashMap as parameter to the next frame(say *SecondFrame*) as follows :

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", name);
data.put("address", address);
data.put("city", city);
data.put("gender", gender);

SecondFrame sf = new SecondFrame(data);
```

Given you have added a constructor for the second frame as follows :

```
public class SecondFrame {

    Map<String, String> data;

    public SecondFrame(Map<String, String> data){
        //user code
    }

    //other methods
}
```

You can get the data from the map as follows :

```
String name = data.get("name");// and so on
```

Comment: Kindly see the picture in the question @arunken I'm taking about 2 Jframes and I'm using JButtons for passing the values sorry but i couldn't understand what you're talking about . As you said I'm doing this behind next button of first frame code 'String name = jTextfield1.getText(); Map <String, String> data= new HashMap<>(); data.put("name", name); SecondFrame sf = new SecondFrame (data); sf.setVisible(true); here it's giving a error as UnSupportedOperation Exception

Comment: We need to import Java.util.Map for this or not